# Issue with Firefox36 and IE11 browser detection

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser-detection

I've made a script to detect browser details (browser version, user agent etc), works fine with chrome but IE11 and FF36 are the issue. From the outset, I had chrome and FF working fine but IE was displaying "Netscape" for the browser name. After doing a bit of research, I found out the "MSIE" token had been removed and replaced with "rv". So I changed the token for IE in my JS to "rv" and ran the script, however when I tested it on FF, it then displayed the browser name as "Microsoft Internet Explorer". So if anyone could give me an insight into why or if i'm missing something in my code that'd be great.

```
    //OS version
        var osversion = navigator.platform;

        var objappVersion = navigator.appVersion;
        var objAgent = navigator.userAgent;
        var objbrowserName = navigator.appName;
        var objfullVersion = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
        var objBrMajorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);
        var objOffsetName, objOffsetVersion, ix;

        // In Chrome 
        if ((objOffsetVersion = objAgent.indexOf("Chrome")) != -1) {
            objbrowserName = "Chrome";
            objfullVersion = objAgent.substring(objOffsetVersion + 7);
        }
        // In Microsoft internet explorer
        else if ((objOffsetVersion = objAgent.indexOf("MSIE")) != -1) {
            objbrowserName = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
            objfullVersion = objAgent.substring(objOffsetVersion + 5);
        }

        // In Firefox
        else if ((objOffsetVersion = objAgent.indexOf("Firefox")) != -1) {
            objbrowserName = "Firefox";
        }
        // In Safari 
        else if ((objOffsetVersion = objAgent.indexOf("Safari")) != -1) {
            objbrowserName = "Safari";
            objfullVersion = objAgent.substring(objOffsetVersion + 7);
            if ((objOffsetVersion = objAgent.indexOf("Version")) != -1)
                objfullVersion = objAgent.substring(objOffsetVersion + 8);
        }
        // For other browser "name/version" is at the end of userAgent 
        else if ((objOffsetName = objAgent.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1) <
                    (objOffsetVersion = objAgent.lastIndexOf('/'))) {
            objbrowserName = objAgent.substring(objOffsetName, objOffsetVersion);
            objfullVersion = objAgent.substring(objOffsetVersion + 1);
            if (objbrowserName.toLowerCase() == objbrowserName.toUpperCase()) {
                objbrowserName = navigator.appName;
            }
        }
        // trimming the fullVersion string at semicolon/space if present
        if ((ix = objfullVersion.indexOf(";")) != -1)
            objfullVersion = objfullVersion.substring(0, ix);
        if ((ix = objfullVersion.indexOf(" ")) != -1)
            objfullVersion = objfullVersion.substring(0, ix);

        objBrMajorVersion = parseInt('' + objfullVersion, 10);
        if (isNaN(objBrMajorVersion)) {
            objfullVersion = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
            objBrMajorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById("browser").innerHTML = objbrowserName;
            document.getElementById("fullV").innerHTML = objfullVersion;
            document.getElementById("majorV").innerHTML = objbrowserName + " " + objBrMajorVersion;
            document.getElementById("appName").innerHTML = navigator.appName;
            document.getElementById("userAgent").innerHTML = navigator.userAgent;
}
```

Comment: FYI IE11+ identifies as mozilla/5.0, there are existing scripts to do this, or use feature detection if possible, which is far superior

Comment: IE has made browser detection difficult. Note also that Edge seems to have a similar strategy, so, put simply, **browser detection is a bad idea in the long run.**

Comment: @Mooseman I created a separate script for IE altogether and then used conditional comments depending on the browser. I know everyones saying stay away from browser detection but it was only as a side project, cheers